# pronunciation: autistic

Tags: pronunciation

> Words comforted and healed my discontent when I discovered that
>   Brendan, my beautiful first-born son was severely ***autistic*** with
>   limited speech.  ([Benita Porter, The Power of Words](http://thisibelieve.org/essay/4210/))
>   - [audio link](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/402)

Which way does the essay writer pronounce: /ɑːˈtɪstɪk/ (1) or /ɔˈtɪstɪk/ (2):

- If she did (2) as is in dictionaries, what’s the difference between (1) and (2)?
  (I hear (1) instead of (2), so I’m wondering what it is. Though I’ve already put the likewise question once on ELL, after getting right answer here from a specific case, I would like to improve my pronunciation understanding better.)
- If she did (1), isn’t there no difference between the two, /ɑ/ and /ɔ/, for some Americans?

Comment: Sounds more like an [ɒ] to me, which is not a phoneme in American English, just an allophone of [ɔ].

Comment: In American English, there is a distinction between /ɔ/ and /a/ for many speakers, but on the West coast, especially, they are merged, to the point where the man's name _Don_ and the woman's name _Dawn_ are both pronounced the same. Since there's no phonemic difference, the actual phonetics varies all over the place from person to person.

Comment: In OP's context it's unambiguous, but I can easily imagine not being able to tell if an American was saying their son was *autistic* or ***artistic***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Um, I would not have any problems differentiating between those words as spoken by most AE speakers because of the hard R. Perhaps a couple East Coast accents like Boston or Jersey (in which "ar" would be pronounced "ah") but for the majority of the US, "artistic" is "are-tistic", and "autistic" is "aw-tistic".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The East Coast accents which pronounce "ar" like "ah" all pronounce "autistic" with /ɔ/. So if you know which variety of American they're speaking, there shouldn't be any ambiguity. It's like complaining that you can't distinguish between an Englishman saying "clerk" and an American saying "clock" ... once they've said a few other words, it should be easy to tell which it is.

Comment: @Peter: I was hoping someone would say something like that! It didn't seem likely the two words would really be homophones to anyone. But in practice I think I personally would probably still figure out the meaning from "circumstantial context" (whether the speaker seemed happy about what they were saying, for example), rather than by "tuning in" to the specific US accent.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think I would "tune in" to the specific US accent, but I certainly can't do it for British accents.

Comment: @Peter: Exactly! You hear the relevant US accents more often, so you can do it there. Just as I naturally latch on to the accent to realise that someone from the North of England is telling me about his ***aunt***, not an ***ant*** who just died (I don't need to think "How sad does he sound?" :)

Comment: ...mind you, I probably would think he was a pretty [sad sack](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sad+sack) if he was telling me about his dead ant!

Comment: Listenever, the voice at your link is American and therefore pronounces the word *autistic*, the American way. It's not the same as how an English person would pronounce it. You can find more sound recordings and phonetic symbols for the word, here http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/autism?q=autistic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In American accent, the pronunciation of the word autistic is as mentioned below :

autistic [aw-tis´tik]